# HTML keeps escaping PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am currently using a plugin that allows me to add get_breadcrumbs to any template. However, i am altering the before and after tag of the current element from span to h2 and it keeps coming out of the `<p id="breadcrumbs">`

What am i doing wrong?

```
function get_breadcrumbs() {

$text['home']     = 'Home'; // text for the 'Home' link
$text['category'] = 'Archive by Category "%s"'; // text for a category page
$text['search']   = 'Search Results for "%s" Query'; // text for a search results page
$text['tag']      = 'Posts Tagged "%s"'; // text for a tag page
$text['author']   = 'Articles Posted by %s'; // text for an author page
$text['404']      = 'Error 404'; // text for the 404 page

$show_current   = 1; // 1 - show current post/page/category title in breadcrumbs, 0 - don't show
$show_on_home   = 0; // 1 - show breadcrumbs on the homepage, 0 - don't show
$show_home_link = 0; // 1 - show the 'Home' link, 0 - don't show
$show_title     = 1; // 1 - show the title for the links, 0 - don't show
$delimiter      = '<span class="sepList">/</span>'; // delimiter between crumbs
$before         = '<h2 class="current">'; // tag before the current crumb
$after          = '</h2>'; // tag after the current crumb
/* === END OF OPTIONS === */

global $post;
$home_link    = home_url('/');
$link_before  = '<span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">';
$link_after   = '</span>';
$link_attr    = ' rel="v:url" property="v:title"';
$link         = $link_before . '<a' . $link_attr . ' href="%1$s">%2$s</a>' . $link_after;
$parent_id    = $parent_id_2 = $post->post_parent;
$frontpage_id = get_option('page_on_front');

if (is_front_page()) {

    if ($show_on_home == 1) echo '<p id="breadcrumbs"><a href="' . $home_link . '">' . $text['home'] . '</a></p>';

} else {

    echo '<p id="breadcrumbs" xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">';
    if ($show_home_link == 1) {
        echo '<span><a href="' . $home_link . '" rel="v:url" property="v:title">' . $text['home'] . '</a></span>';
        if ($frontpage_id == 0 || $parent_id != $frontpage_id) echo $delimiter;
    }

    if ( is_category() ) {
        $this_cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'), false);
        if ($this_cat->parent != 0) {
            $cats = get_category_parents($this_cat->parent, TRUE, $delimiter);
            if ($show_current == 0) $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)$delimiter$#", "$1", $cats);
            $cats = str_replace('<a', $link_before . '<a' . $link_attr, $cats);
            $cats = str_replace('</a>', '</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
            if ($show_title == 0) $cats = preg_replace('/ title="(.*?)"/', '', $cats);
            echo $cats;
        }
        if ($show_current == 1) echo $before . sprintf($text['category'], single_cat_title('', false)) . $after;

    } elseif ( is_search() ) {
        echo $before . sprintf($text['search'], get_search_query()) . $after;

    } elseif (is_home()) {
        echo $before . 'Blog' . $after;

    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
        echo sprintf($link, get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')), get_the_time('Y')) . $delimiter;
        echo sprintf($link, get_month_link(get_the_time('Y'),get_the_time('m')), get_the_time('F')) . $delimiter;
        echo $before . get_the_time('d') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
        echo sprintf($link, get_year_link(get_the_time('Y')), get_the_time('Y')) . $delimiter;
        echo $before . get_the_time('F') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
        echo $before . get_the_time('Y') . $after;

    } elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
        if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
            $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
            $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
            printf($link, $home_link . '/' . $slug['slug'] . '/', $post_type->labels->singular_name);
            if ($show_current == 1) echo $delimiter . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
        } else {
            $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
            $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, $delimiter);
            if ($show_current == 0) $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)$delimiter$#", "$1", $cats);
            $cats = str_replace('<a', $link_before . '<a' . $link_attr, $cats);
            $cats = str_replace('</a>', '</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
            if ($show_title == 0) $cats = preg_replace('/ title="(.*?)"/', '', $cats);
            echo $cats;
            if ($show_current == 1) echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
        }

    } elseif ( !is_single() && !is_page() && get_post_type() != 'post' && !is_404() ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
        echo $before . $post_type->labels->singular_name . $after;

    } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
        $parent = get_post($parent_id);
        $cat = get_the_category($parent->ID); $cat = $cat[0];
        $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, $delimiter);
        $cats = str_replace('<a', $link_before . '<a' . $link_attr, $cats);
        $cats = str_replace('</a>', '</a>' . $link_after, $cats);
        if ($show_title == 0) $cats = preg_replace('/ title="(.*?)"/', '', $cats);
        echo $cats;
        printf($link, get_permalink($parent), $parent->post_title);
        if ($show_current == 1) echo $delimiter . $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && !$parent_id ) {
        if ($show_current == 1) echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;

    } elseif ( is_page() && $parent_id ) {
        if ($parent_id != $frontpage_id) {
            $breadcrumbs = array();
            while ($parent_id) {
                $page = get_page($parent_id);
                if ($parent_id != $frontpage_id) {
                    $breadcrumbs[] = sprintf($link, get_permalink($page->ID), get_the_title($page->ID));
                }
                $parent_id = $page->post_parent;
            }
            $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($breadcrumbs); $i++) {
                echo $breadcrumbs[$i];
                if ($i != count($breadcrumbs)-1) echo $delimiter;
            }
        }
        if ($show_current == 1) {
            if ($show_home_link == 1 || ($parent_id_2 != 0 && $parent_id_2 != $frontpage_id)) echo $delimiter;
            echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
        }

    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
        echo $before . sprintf($text['tag'], single_tag_title('', false)) . $after;

    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
        global $author;
        $userdata = get_userdata($author);
        echo $before . sprintf($text['author'], $userdata->display_name) . $after;

    } elseif ( is_404() ) {
        echo $before . $text['404'] . $after;
    }

    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ' (';
        echo __('Page') . ' ' . get_query_var('paged');
        if ( is_category() || is_day() || is_month() || is_year() || is_search() || is_tag() || is_author() ) echo ')';
    }

    echo '</p><!-- .breadcrumbs -->';

  }
}
```

Output

```
<p id="breadcrumbs" xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#"><span><a href="#" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Home</a></span><span class="separate"> » </span></p>

<h2 class="current">Archive by Category "News"</h2>
```

The h2 should be within the `<p id="breadcrumbs">` but its just come out.

---

**UPDATED**

I have just tested on what works and what doesnt and its only when i insert the `h2` tag within the function variable `$before` and `$after`. When i insert the `span` tags, it works fine.

**WORKS:**

```
$before         = '<span class="current">'; // tag before the current crumb
$after          = '</span>'; // tag after the current crumb
```

**DOESNT WORK: (REQUIRED)**

```
$before         = '<h2 class="current">'; // tag before the current crumb
$after          = '</h2>'; // tag after the current crumb
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you looking at the source or the development tools? I'm pretty sure you cannot put a `h2` inside a `p` tag so the browser might be trying to correct your html.

Comment: @jeroen thank you. Did some research and you are correct. Thanks again.